# How to intercept events sent to MailItem

Tags: c++, outlook-addin

I would like to intercept `MailItem` events sent to the `MailItem` of a specific `Inspector`, particularly `MailItem.Close`.  Unfortunately Microsoft's documentations are very scarce in details and I haven't found any information on the subject. Does anyone know if it's possible to intercept item-level events sent to `MailItem` objects associated with `Inspector` instances?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I am not sure what the problem is - retrieve `MailItem` from `Inspector.CurrentItem`, subscribe to its events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you happen to know if there is any minimal working example on how to intercept events?

Comment: I am not aware of one. Are you running into a particular problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to discard changes made to a mail body that avoids showing the user the "properties have changed" dialog box, and apparently one strategy is to intercept close events sent from the `Inspector` to trigger a call to `MailItem.Close` with the `olDiscard` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible. You just need to create an inspector wrapper for implementing the required functionality. Take a look at the following articles and sample projects:

- [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to: Implement a Wrapper for Inspectors and Track Item-Level Events in Each Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184620.aspx)
- [Outlook 2010: Developing an Inspector Wrapper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Outlook-2010-Developing-an-c4470591)